# 400 Bad Request response: KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to use amazon dynamodb in my php application. I have setup the credential correctly. Now, I am trying to get the data from the Amazon DynamoDB to my application. But it is giving me an exception at the query line.

The full exception error is

> Unable to query: Error executing "Query" on "https://dynamodb.my-region.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://dynamodb.my-region.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression (truncated...) ValidationException (client): Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request. - {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException","message":"Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request."}

Here is my code,

```
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
        'region' => 'my region',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => 'my key',
            'secret' => 'my secret key'
        ],
        'DynamoDb' => [
            'region' => 'my region',
        ],
    ]);

    $dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
    $marshaler = new Marshaler();

    $tableName = 'My Table Name';

    $params = [
        'TableName' => $tableName
    ];

    try {
        $result = $dynamodb->query($params);
    } catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
        echo "Unable to query:\n";
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

The error is coming from the try-catch block. Can anybody give me the reason and solution of this error? 
Any suggestion for this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the dynamodb on local before executing the program ?

Comment: Yes, I am running the dynamodb on local before excuting the program not @notionquest . The dynamodb is working fine. But my database table is in aws console. Is it the problem?

Comment: If the tables are in AWS region, you need to remove the endpoint parameter. 'endpoint' => 'http://localhost:8000'. The API will determine the endpoint based on the region specified.

Comment: I have removed the endpoint parameter. Now this is giving me this error @notionquest
Unable to query: Error executing "Query" on "https://dynamodb.my-region.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please add the `KeyConditionExpression` with values.

```
 $params = [
        'TableName' => $tableName,
        'KeyConditionExpression' => 'yourHashKey = :v_hash'
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
                  ':v_hash'  => array('S' => 'Hash_Value')
             )
    ];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a KeyConditions in your $params in order to query. This documentation can help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html